# How do you make things instant build in CK2?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

How do you make things instant build in CK2? I tried to look up commands but I couldn't find any. From a long time ago I sort of remember there was one but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3):

No such option exists in the standard game. If you want things built in your own holdings, you have to order it yourself. Your vassals should upgrade their own holdings by themselves as their own money is available.

If you are interested in some mods there is one that allows you to setup a build order available here: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=345788750&searchtext=

OR here:
http://www.moddb.com/mods/auto-build-mini-mod-and-generator

that's about the best you can do I think.

Answer (score 3):

According to [CK2's wikia page:](http://crusaderkings-two.wikia.com/wiki/Cheats)

> The console is opened by pressing § + Shift. Alt + 2 1 or ~ may also work ( ~ seems to be the majority console button, located beneath esc ). The cheat console is a transparent overlay above the character's tab.

Although, on my keyboard neither works and I have to do Shift + ` + space

---

> quickbuild = Player's construction are finished immediately (One day).

Answer (score 0):

open the console and type quickbuild

Comment: Welcome to the site. While you provide an answer to the question, please describe how the console  is opened. try to be as complete and thorough as possible.

Comment: So you downvote instead of editing... gosh

Comment: @Oak It's not required that anyone fix other people's mistakes, and you're making a couple of big assumptions, that Dulkan is the downvoter and that Dulkan knows how to open the console in CK2.